# How to interpret the encoding circuit for the 5-qubit QECC

Tags: circuit-construction, quantum-circuit, pauli-gates

I have a question on circuit which constitutes the sydnrome measurement for the 5-qubit error correcting code. If I focus on just a portion of the circuit:

[image]

[Reference for image](https://www.physics.unlv.edu/%7Ebernard/MATH_book/Chap9/Notebook9_3.pdf). The full circuit can be found on page $3$ of the Notebook just referenced.

So I have a five qubit state $|\psi\rangle$ and an ancilla qubit in the $|0\rangle$ state.

If, for example, we say the state $|\psi\rangle = |0_{5L}\rangle$, I am a litte confused as to the circuit works.

My understanding would be (and please note I think I am quite wrong about this):

1. We begin with the $|000000\rangle$ state
2. We apply the Hadamard operator to the first qubit, so the resulting state is $|+00000\rangle$
3. The 1st qubit is the control qubit and the 2nd qubit is the target qubit. But I am not quite sure how this works for the Pauli matrices? I know that for the CNOT operation, if the control qubit is in the $|1\rangle$ state, then the target qubit undergoes a bit flip. How does this work in this circuit with the Pauli matrices?
4. I have the same gap in understanding for the next few steps.

---

From Nielsen and Chuang's textbook, $$|c\rangle |t\rangle \rightarrow |c\rangle U^{c}|t\rangle$$ "If the control qubit is set than $U$ is applied to the target, otherwise it is left alone."

So perhaps my question would be better summarised as, what does it mean for the control qubit to be "set"?

Comment: can you add the source of the image/question?

Comment: Oops, edited the question to include the source for the picture, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...From Nielsen and Chuang's textbook, $$|c> |t> \rightarrow |c> U^{c}|t>$$ "If the control qubit is set than $U$ is applied to the target, otherwise it is left alone."
>
> So perhaps my question would be better summarised as, what does it mean for the control qubit to be "set"?

The control qubit is "set" if it is $|1\rangle$ and not set if it is $|0\rangle$.

In this answer I will use the $\otimes$ symbol to indicate the direct product of qubits. So, instead of writing $|a\rangle|b\rangle$ I will write $|a\rangle\otimes|b\rangle$.

With the above notation we have, for example:
$$
|0\rangle\otimes|t\rangle\to|0\rangle\otimes|t\rangle
$$
and
$$
|1\rangle\otimes|t\rangle\to|1\rangle \otimes\left(U|t\rangle\right)
$$

And for an arbitrary superposition of the control bit:
$$
\left(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle\right)\otimes|t\rangle
\to
\left(\alpha|0\rangle\otimes|t\rangle+\beta|1\rangle\otimes(U|t\rangle)\right)
$$

---

You can also understand the action of a controlled $U$ gate in terms of projection operators. The controlled $U$ gate can be written as:
$$
|0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes \mathbf{1} + |1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes U
$$